# Vaadin 7 and browser url update

Tags: vaadin, vaadin7

My Vaadin 7 application doesn't react on browser url changing. For example I entering from keyboard a new url parameters and pressing Enter key and after that nothing is changing.

Application only reacts on F5 or page refresh button.

How to also make Vaadin 7 application to respond to Enter key after url update ?

**UPDATED**

I'm using Vaadin `com.vaadin.navigator.Navigator` object.

For example I have an url: http://example.com/#!products/30970

When I change the url in browser address bar (for example to http://example.com/#!products/34894) and press enter key I would like to change information at my page in order to show info about product with id 34894 instead of product with a previous id 30970.

**Vaadin Navigator and UriFragmentChangedListener**

Right now I'm using Vaadin `Navigator` in order to define views:

```
    Navigator navigator = new Navigator(this, viewDisplay);

    navigator.addView("products", ProductView.class);
```

First time in web browser I'm successfully able to access this view with product `id` parameter for example by the following url:

```
http://example.com/#!products/30970
```

`ProductView` is constructed first time and in its `public void enter(ViewChangeListener.ViewChangeEvent event)` method I'm able to get uri parameters.

But after that when I change product id in web browser address bar in this url to another one(for example to `30971` in order to display information for another product):

```
http://example.com/#!products/30971
```

and press Enter key the view is not refreshed and doesn't react on these changes..

As suggested in the comments I have added `UriFragmentChangedListener` listener and now at least able to handle URL fragment changes(after Enter key presing).

**Now, my logic have to react on these changes and I'm looking for a correct way how it should be implemented in Vaadin 7.**

So, If I understood correctly - in additional to Navigator logic I also have to use this listener and inside of this listener logic I have to get a reference on appropriate view(`navigator.getCurrentView()` ?) object and invoke some method on this object in order to change internal view state without full view rebuild ? If I'm correct - is there some standard mechanism in Vaadin in order to simplify this job ?

Comment: Are you using a [navigator](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-navigator.html), a [FragmentChangeListener](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-urifu.html) or a [RequestHandler](https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-requesthandler.html)? Please provide more details and perhaps show some code and explain what you'd expect it to behave like.

Comment: @Morfic I have updated my question with more detailed information

Comment: Have you added a listener which listens on URL changes? This might help as well https://vaadin.com/docs/-/part/framework/advanced/advanced-urifu.html

Comment: @AndréSchild thanks, I have added this listener and now at least able to handle URL fragment changes. So, If I understood correctly - inside of this  listener based in URI fragment I need to get a reference on appropriate view(navigator.getCurrentView() ?) object and invoke some method on this object in order to change internal view state without full view rebuild ? If I'm correct - is there some standard mechanism in Vaadin in order to simplify this job ?

Comment: @alexanoid Usually you either use the Navigator for this (But you have to tell the Navigator about each URL) or you handle it yourself with the fragments

Comment: I use the Navigator right now in order to associate a View with base URI fragment name but URI fragments can contain a different parameters and based on this parameters I need to show different data at this view. So this is my question about - how to correctly handle view changes based on different parameters in URI and change the view content after providing another parameters to the same view.

Comment: If you can make a SSCCE, I will debug it.

Comment: Thanks but right now first I'd like to understand the correct approach how it should be implemented with Vaadin 7. I have updated my question one more time with more details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

i can not think of another way than pass the UriFragmentChangeEvent manually to your View. I guess the Vaadin API can not do it automatic.

```
public class MyUI extends UI{

    @Override
    protected void init(final VaadinRequest request) {

        /*
         * UriFragmentChangedListener
         * when URL+Parameter manuell eingegeben werden 
         */
        getPage().addUriFragmentChangedListener(new UriFragmentChangedListener() {

            @Override
            public void uriFragmentChanged(UriFragmentChangedEvent event) {

                View currentView = getNavigator().getCurrentView();
                if(currentView != null){

                    if(currentView instanceof UriFragmentChangedListener){
                        ((UriFragmentChangedListener)currentView).uriFragmentChanged(event); //custom method
                    }

                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

To make this work add UriFragmentChangedListener to your ProductView:

```
public class ProductView extends CustomComponent implements View, UriFragmentChangedListener {

}
```

Comment: Thanks,  I'll test it

Answer (score 0):

take a look at the Parameters in the ViewChangeEvent of your ProductView

By using this url structure "http://example.com/#!products/30970", you can read the product id as following:

```
@Override
public void enter(ViewChangeEvent event) {

    String productId = event.getParameters();
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but this method does not invoke when I change the URI params in the same view.

Comment: sorry, did not saw this in your post.